# Leaves of a tree - are they max-heaps by definition?

Tags: heap

As I understand, a max-heap is binary tree where the parent is either greater than, or smaller than its right/left child respectively.

Does this mean that a leaf of a binary tree is by definition a max-heap?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a leaf of a tree is itself a heap. In other words, a tree with just one node is a heap -- both a min-heap and a max-heap, since there is no second value to compare with.

This is also the reason why the typical [heap building process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) (given an array), starts with an index in the middle of the array. This references the last node that still is a parent. Quoting Wikipedia:

> The array elements indexed by floor(/2) + 1, floor(/2) + 2, ...,  are all leaves for the tree (assuming that indices start at 1) — thus each is a one-element heap, and does not need to be down-heapified.